# xml android application scrollable relative layout

Tags: android, xml

Im trying to create a app but it wont all fit on the screen. I have tried to use Scroll View amongst other things and just cant seem to get it right. Do I need a table and make the table scrollable? When I use Scroll View it seems to make it a linear layout but Im using a relative layout? None of the other answers on here seem to work.
as you can see its quite cramped

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/black_white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/North"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="North"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/East"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/North"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="East"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/South"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/address"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="South"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/West"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/address"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/South"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="West"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/North"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Address"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/East"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Visit Website"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/address"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="address" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/East"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Map &amp; Directions"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/CheckedTextView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Phone"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CheckedTextView01"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/East"
    android:src="@drawable/aphone" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/East"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:hint="Call Us"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:text="1-614-555-5555"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/CheckedTextView02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="E-Mail"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CheckedTextView02"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:src="@drawable/themail" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Send Message"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/CheckedTextView03"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Website"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:src="@drawable/mapicon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RelativeLayout scrollview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657687/relativelayout-scrollview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your RelativeLayout inside a scrollview

**Make sure you set the layout_width and height set to match_parent**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

     <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/black_white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

put your other stuff here
.
.
.

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong but this does work. android:layout_width and android:layout_height was wrong